# Can't get `MouseEventArgs` in `MouseHover` event

Tags: c#, charts, mouseevent, mousehover

I'm sure this has a straight forward answer but I can't seem to figure it out.

I am trying to add a `tooltip` using my `mousehover` event. Historically I have used the `mousemove` event but unfortunately this means the `tooltip` gets updated as fast as the program can do it. I just want it to show when the mouse is stationary on my graph.

The issue is that I can't get the `e.Location` property because the event handler only uses `EventArgs`, not `MouseEventArgs`. Is there a way I can change this? Or maybe add a line like `MouseEventArgs mouse = new MouseEventArgs();` (I get an error saying it needs more arguments, but I don't know which).

Any help is appreciated :)

```
        private void chSysData_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Add tooltip
            try
            {
                int cursorX = Convert.ToInt32(chSysData.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.PixelPositionToValue(e.Location.X));
                tipInfo = "System: " + systemVoltage[cursorX].ToString("0.00") + Environment.NewLine + "Current: " + currArray[cursorX].ToString("0.00") + Environment.NewLine;
                tooltip.SetToolTip(chSysData, tipInfo);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Map the Cursor.Position property to your chart.  An example with a panel:

```
    private void panel1_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        var pos = panel1.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
        toolTip1.Show("Hello", panel1, pos);
    }
```

Note that this is not otherwise different from using toolTip1.Show("Hello", panel1); but you are likely to want to tweak the tooltip position so it isn't overlapped by the cursor.

Comment: I'm reading up on this error: `Member 'System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.get' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead`. I've never seen it before. Any suggestions while I try to figure it out?

Comment: "Cursor" is the type name, not the name of an object.  Make sure that doesn't clash with a variable you use in your code, you are using names like "cursorX".  If that doesn't help then click the Ask Question button to better document your problem.

Comment: I just searched my program and no variable named `Cursor`. I'll keep digging around first before I ask another question. I don't like to ask unless I have researched it for myself first. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Figured it out: ` var pos = chSysData.PointToClient(System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position);`. Thanks again!